# Basic Input to Output

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am a teacher in the Uk and we use basic curriculum levels, which range from 1 to 8 for KS3.  A pupil entering secondary school would be about a Level 4 or 5 in maths.  However each level in then subdivided into Low, Secure and High, and hence we say 4l,4s,4h, 5l,5s,5h etc.

For ease of data handling the gov then made a points scheme, that 4l = 27 points, 4s = 28, 4h = 29, 5l = 30 etc upto 8h.

The school requires us to say level grades on our spreadsheets but we want to then give points score and then rank.

If col. A is their name, B is their test percentage, C is their grade (all inputted by us) can i make col. D auto look up C and replace with their points score? And then Col E rank them on this score at first level and their test percentage % as a secondary level? (Can not just be on % as different maths sets have different tests but all standardised using levels)

Tried IF funtion but can only imput 8 variables to not enough.  Maybe LOOKUP or MATCH or INDEX?

Thanks Olly-

Answer (score 1):

Try a vertical lookup `vlookup`:

Create a new sheet with the grade table, with grades on the left:

```
Sheet2:
    A     B
1   4l    27
2   4s    28
3   4h    29
```

We'll search for values in column A and return the values in column B.

Then in sheet1, for column D use:

```
D2=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

C2 is the value we want to look for in the new table we created. It will always search the first/leftmost column. Sheet2!A:B is the range, the entire two columns on Sheet 2. "2" means if it finds a hit, return the value in the second column of the range we defined (the B column in this case). And FALSE tells it to only accept exact matches, otherwise it will return close-enough matches (good if you have a range of grades rather than one-to-one values to look up). Then just copy the formula down the entire D column on sheet1, and you can rename or hide Sheet2 if you like to keep it tidy.

Comment: Worked a treat on my test!